# If number is greater than in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, int

Ok I need help if I have this code and I wanted to know if there was a way to detect if the number is greater than the one in the textbox?

```
if (textbox1.text == "2")
{
     //code
}
```

and I was wondering is there anyway to detect if the number is greater than that so say `textbox1.text = "5"` it is greater than 2 so therefore it does the code from the if command?

Comment: What do you want to do if the value isn't a number?

Comment: Are you talking about code that will run in the user's browser or code that will run on your server?

Comment: well i'm making a clock and when it goes over the curtain time then it runs a code or acts as textbox1.text = "2"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want? Is it you want the textbox value to be tested against another number? If so why not: if(textbox.Text < someNumber) ? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out value))
{
   if (value > 2)
     // code
}
else
{
    // not a number in textbox
}
```

---

Sample for your real application:

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().TimeOfDay;

if (8 < timeOfDay.Hours && timeOfDay.Hours < 16)
{
    // day
}
else
{
    // night
}
```

You can create extension method:

```
public static bool IsDayTime(this DateTime date)
{
    TimeSpan timeOfDay = date.TimeOfDay;
    return 8 < timeOfDay.Hours && timeOfDay.Hours < 16;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
var file = Path.Combine(Folder, date.IsDayTime() ? "Day.bmp" : "Night.bmp");
picThumbnail.ImageLocation = file;
picThumbnail.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, file, 0x01 | 0x02);
var rkWallPaper = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
rkWallPaper.SetValue("WallpaperStyle", 2);
rkWallPaper.SetValue("TileWallpaper", 0);
rkWallPaper.Close();
```

Comment: ok this is great thanks and sorry i didn't explain what i men't right but i have a textbox and its got this written in it "11:43:00" so its a string and it won't convert to int because of the ":" i need to find a way to add them in.

Comment: This string looks like time. Is it? If yes, then use `TimeSpan.TryParse(str, out time)` to parse `TimeSpan` from your string.

Comment: Thanks but i got it see here:

Comment: @Terrii your code looks strange - you are parsing hours+minutes+seconds as integer. What it supposed to mean? What is 8000 is it supposed to be total seconds?

Comment: well what its doing is its setting a time.text to this "111111" which is 11hr 11min 11 sec but its compressed them all into one label so 8000 is 8:00am and 16000 is 8:00pm therefor when its 8:00am then it sets a daytime photo as the desktop background then when its 8:00pm then it sets a night time photo.

Comment: 80 = 8/hr the next 0 is 0/mins and the last 0 = 0/sec so they add up to make 8000

Comment: @Terrii I've added sample for your real task

Answer (score 2):

Parse the text value and then check it...

`if(Convert.ToInt32(Textbox.Text) > 2) { //Do something here }`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Int32.Parse(textbox1.text) < number)
{
   // code
}
```

and catch any exceptions for the case of invalid values. Or use `TryParse` which has an `out` argument and returns whether a number was actually parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the text as a number and then you can do what you want.

C#'s Int32 class has a TryParse method that you use like so:

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(textbox1.text, out number);

if (number > 2)
{
  ...
}
```

This is a method that has an input value *and* an output value.  The `bool` result is actually an indicator of whether the attempt (the 'Try') to parse the input value has worked, and you can use it defensively as follows:

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(textbox1.text, out number);

if (result)
{
  // the parse worked
  // do something with 'number'
}
else
{
    Messagebox.Show(string.Format("Could not convert {0} to a number", textbox1.text));
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using TryParse if you don't take its result into account?

Comment: You use the bool `result` to see if the method worked. I'll edit the answer to explain better.